# Postgres return grouped results and pass results based on the group in another query

Tags: sql, postgresql

How can I do this is postgres SQL
My table below gives me all the accounts on each group

```
account | groupName
1       | group1
2       | group1
2nyc    | group1
2lon    | group2
3       | group2
4       | group2
```

Based on the groups, i needs to get the accounts and pass them in another sql. 
I needs the results from all the groups.

So far what I've tried is

```
WITH main_data AS (
SELECT 
    account, groupName  
FROM 
    accountMapping  
WHERE 
    groupName IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY account, groupName  

)
SELECT * FROM results_table where account in (SELECT account FROM main_data);
```

I need it so that logically this should be the same as doing this

```
SELECT * FROM results_table WHERE account in (1, 2,2nyc);
SELECT * FROM results_table WHERE account in (3, 4)
```

... and so on

Comment: Please edit your question and show the results that you want to obtain.

Comment: I've edited this. please let me know if this is still unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT rt.*
FROM results_table 
WHERE rt.account IN (SELECT am.account
                     FROM accountMapping am
                     WHERE am.groupName = $groupName
                    );
```